# How to upload and add images to the existing post from the front-end with admin approval which is posted by other user

Tags: uploads, front-end, dashboard

I want, by admin approval, that a logged in user can upload a image and add to the post which is posted by other user. He should add the image to the post from the Front-End.

Comment: Why does it seem that questions like these are asked by freelancers promising things to clients and then asking WPSE to write all the code for them? Preferably ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to add post images and other things. So put different check on it according to your need.

```
<?php
    if( 'POST'  == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD' ] && !empty( $_POST['action' ] ) &&  $_POST['action' ] == "new_post") {
                if (isset ($_POST['post_title'])) {
                        $post_title =  $_POST['post_title'];
                    }


            $post = array(
                        'post_title'    => $post_title,
                        'post_content'  => $post_content,
                        'post_category' => array($post_category),
                        'tags_input'    => array($post_tags),
                        'post_status'   => 'draft',
                        'post_type' => 'post'
                    );

                $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
                wp_set_post_tags($post_id, $post_tags);


                if (!empty($_FILES['file_0']['name'])) {
                  foreach ($_FILES as $file_id => $array) {
                    $attachment_id = insert_attachment($file_id,$post_id,true);
                  }
                 //send_mail_on_post_submit($userEmail);
            $success = __('This post is awaiting approval by the moderators', 'frontendprofile');


            }
            unset($_POST);


    }
    ?>
```